# how to resolve FIXUPREDIRECT urls into MMS urls in List Item Page Content

Tags: custom-list, managed-metadata, managed-navigation, managed-metadata-service

I have a custom list and one of the columns is "Page Content" added from existing columns. If I add a site link in this HTML field for example url is "/en/about-us/" (I use Managed Metadata) it all looks fine. Edit form displays proper SEO link. Bu when I use custom code to get value either in C# or PowerShell I see HTML code of that field is like

```
<p> <a href=\"/sites/sbf/_layouts/15/FIXUPREDIRECT.ASPX?WebId=6bebabdc-7d82-462d-b75e-0dba798164fd&amp;TermSetId=cf1b86bc-56c8-4313-83d7-5a0bcef18add&amp;TermId=90de1397-4863-420f-8593-e3e4e7dd5784\"> ​Test ​</a> ​</p>
```

If I go and edit this list item i see the proper SEO url again.

My question is how can I resolve all links in HTML so I can display them properly in my code?